# Ubuntu 22.04 won't wake up from sleep

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management, shutdown

**Ubuntu 22.04 won't wake up from sleep**

### 1.issue

- Whenever the laptop suspends (either due to a closed lid or due to a
  black screen for a certain time), I cannot wake it up.
  2. The laptop does not respond to keystrokes and power button clicks. As a result, I always have to hold the power button to shut
  it down and then power it up again.

### 2.system

- Model: asus vivobool 14
- AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics
- Storage: 512GB SSD
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64bit

### 3.update

- Tried GRUB_CMD_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0" in grub config and it didn't
  work.
- Tried GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1" in grub config and it
  didn't work.
- -tried and install nvidia-driver-465 package and it didn't work.

Comment: Both me and my colleagues have been having the same issue since about a month back, in our case Asus ZenBook 13, also with AMD Ryzen but the7 5700u. It worked fine before then and broke for all of us at the same time so it's related to one of the more resent kernel changes.

Comment: Why install nvidia drivers when you have Radeon Graphics?

Comment: This problem recurs for me about every third update. The USB power gets disabled, so keystrokes/mouse won't wake the computer. Do an 'lsusb' and see what bus/device your keyboard is on. Mine is 1-3. Looking in /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/power/wakeup I'll find a 'disabled'. Changing this to 'enabled' fixes the problem (until a future update). I now have a script to fix this it has been going on so long.

Comment: The question said ***"and power button clicks"***, meaning that the keyboard is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using Ubuntu 22.04 and experienced the same problem. After some digging around, I found that source of the problem is probably nvidia drivers, so I launched *Software & Updates* -> *Additional Drivers*.

[image: Software & Updates]

And I changed the driver from *nvidia-driver-525* (proprietary) to *nvidia-driver-525-open* (proprietary).

This reinstalled the driver, and after rebooting the problem disappeared.

Comment: but I am not getting any additional drivers.

Comment: With this involving NVIDIA card instructions when the asker clearly indicated using an AMD/ATI card, I am downvoting this. AMD/ATI cards aren't driven by NVIDIA drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Dell XPS 9550
in Ubuntu 22.04 I tried next steps:

1. added  mem_sleep_default=deep to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT (/etc/default/grub) - didn't help
2. added WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf (under [daemon]) - didn't help
3. installed mainline and kernel 6.4.11-060411-generic (latest kernel in mainline as for 2023-08-17) - now wake up from sleep is working. While installing new kernel, there were errors but kernel was installed and I can enter into Ubuntu. But somehow time expected to run at previous kernel (6.2) were from 3 to 8 hours, now battery shows stable 1 hour 45 - for 45 percent of battery and ~3hours 30 minutes for 100 percent battery. Maybe it was the statistics errors in previous kernels. but 3 hours 30 minutes at web-browsing and visual studio code and telegram are ok for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just curious why did you install NVIDIA drivers when you have Radeon Graphics hardware.

I am also facing this problem now. I have a AMD Radeon RX6600M, and have installed the latest AMD driver available for that but still not able to resolve the issue. I came across a temporary solution suggested in other posts, and it is to use 1) Ctrl + Alt + F3, then, 2) Ctrl + Alt + (F2 or F7) depends on the Manufacturer. I haven't tried it, I am searching for the permanent solution. Just in case, if you were able to solve it, please share it here. Thanks.