# Ubuntu 22.04 : Laptop don't wake up after suspend

Tags: suspend, asus, cpu, resume, standby

I have a problem on an Asus VivoBook 17 on Ubuntu 22.04 (clean install)
Everything seems to work fine, except suspend mode : after, the computer doesn't want to do anything : black screen (as in suspend), and mouse click / trackpad / keyboard don't do anything, I have to push power button 5sec to force the computer to standby. After a restart, it works fine (until suspend...)

At startup, I saw this (briefly) :

```
12:33:10 kernel: FAT-fs (sdc1): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
11:51:13 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
11:51:04 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xe57d2000-0xe57d2fff]
11:51:04 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
```

So I updated the BIOS from version 302 (or something) to 310 (Serial Number : X705QA)
But it doesn't changed anything.

As seen in this question : [Ubuntu 22.04 won't wake up from sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457833/ubuntu-22-04-wont-wake-up-from-sleep) that it may be due to drivers. But no additional drivers were found (just one for wifi card, but WiFi works fine, so I didn't change that)

I don't know how to do it; someone here has an idea?

Some informations :

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models
60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
[AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev ca)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini
HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
Carrizo Platform Security Processor
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Audio
Dummy Host Bridge
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI
Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA
Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 49)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI
Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller
(rev 4a)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge
(rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h
(Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE
802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5a11 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3529 IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129
Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Computer :

```
ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. VivoBook_ASUS Laptop X705QA_R702QA
Asus VivoBook 17
Serial Number : X705QA
BIOS version 310 (updated from 302?)
AMD® A10-9620p radeon r5, 10 compute cores 4c+6g × 4
CARRIZO (carrizo, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.47, 5.19.0-50-generic)
```

Also some logs of a session where I made the computer to suspend

```
12:36:26 gdm-session-wor: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=fred
12:36:25 gnome-shell: JS ERROR: Failed to initialize fprintd service: Gio.IOErrorEnum: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:114:23

12:36:25 systemd: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
12:36:25 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
12:36:25 fprintd: Failed to install a sleep delay inhibitor: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
12:36:25 systemd: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
12:36:25 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.45' (uid=1000 pid=1092 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
12:36:21 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp1s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
12:36:21 NetworkManager: <info>  [1690626981.4095] device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
12:36:21 systemd-resolve: wlp1s0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
12:36:21 avahi-daemon: Interface wlp1s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
12:36:21 NetworkManager: <info>  [1690626981.3771] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed no lease
12:36:21 gnome-shell: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
12:36:21 avahi-daemon: Interface wlp1s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
12:36:21 NetworkManager: <info>  [1690626981.3511] device (wlp1s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
12:36:21 wpa_supplicant: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
12:36:21 systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
12:36:21 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
12:36:21 systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
12:36:21 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.6' (uid=0 pid=741 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
12:36:21 ModemManager: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
12:36:14 update-notifier: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
12:35:57 systemd: app-gnome-thunderbird-5707.scope: Consumed 39.844s CPU time.
12:34:54 wpa_supplicant: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-63 noise=9999 txrate=40500
12:33:28 systemd: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
12:33:24 gnome-shell: Window manager warning: last_focus_time (2544325) is greater than comparison timestamp (2544324).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending inaccurate timestamps in messages such as _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Trying to work around...
12:33:18 wpa_supplicant: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=9999 txrate=117000
12:33:18 systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
12:33:18 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
12:33:18 systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
12:33:18 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.6' (uid=0 pid=741 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
12:33:18 NetworkManager: <info>  [1690626798.2210] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.18
12:33:16 wpa_supplicant: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-63 noise=9999 txrate=292500
12:33:16 NetworkManager: <info>  [1690626796.0548] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
12:33:16 wpa_supplicant: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to dc:00:b0:b5:c1:5c completed [id=0 id_str=]
12:33:16 NetworkManager: <info>  [1690626796.0157] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
12:33:16 kernel: wlp1s0: associated
12:33:15 NetworkManager: <info>  [1690626795.9989] device (wlp1s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
12:33:15 wpa_supplicant: wlp1s0: Trying to associate with dc:00:b0:b5:c1:5c (SSID='freebox_LSSIZN' freq=5200 MHz)
12:33:10 systemd: media-fred-USB.mount: Deactivated successfully.
12:33:10 kernel: FAT-fs (sdc1): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
12:33:10 udisksd: Cleaning up mount point /media/fred/USB (device 8:33 no longer exists)
12:33:10 kernel: usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
12:33:08 gnome-shell: JS ERROR: TypeError: this.window_container is null
hideOverlay@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowPreview.js:373:9
vfunc_leave_event/this._idleHideOverlayId<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowPreview.js:571:26

12:33:03 wpa_supplicant: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-60 noise=9999 txrate=1000
12:32:48 systemd: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
12:32:39 avahi-daemon: Registering new address record for 2a01:e0a:5b6:f0c0:8a74:d281:4ce0:664b on wlp1s0.*.
12:32:37 systemd-resolve: wlp1s0: Bus client set DNS server list to: 192.168.0.200, 1.1.1.1, 2a01:e0a:5b6:f0c0:5df2:eed0:37f1:5b9c, 2606:4700:4700::1111
12:32:37 avahi-daemon: Withdrawing address record for fe80::3e69:a166:d584:e0f5 on wlp1s0.
12:32:37 NetworkManager: <info>  [1690626757.4322] policy: set 'freebox_LSSIZN' (wlp1s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
12:32:35 wpa_supplicant: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-58 noise=9999 txrate=26000
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT :

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i tpm
[    0.000000] efi: TPMFinalLog=0xe579a000 ACPI 2.0=0xe5699000
ACPI=0xe5699000 SMBIOS=0xe5a00000 SMBIOS 3.0=0xe59ff000 ESRT=0xe32a2b18
MEMATTR=0xe329c018 MOKvar=0xe5883000 RNG=0xe5698018 TPMEventLog=0xe20e3018
[    0.007250] ACPI: TPM2 0x00000000E56B54D8 000034 (v04 _ASUS_ Notebook
00000001 AMI  00000000)
[    0.007304] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem
0xe56b54d8-0xe56b550b]
[    1.166879] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not
cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xe57d2000-0xe57d2fff
flags 0x200] vs e57d2000 4000
[    1.166896] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource
[mem 0xe57d2000-0xe57d2fff]
[    1.166902] tpm_crb: probe of MSFT0101:00 failed with error -16
[    1.267930] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
```

```
$ journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1day'
juil. 29 11:06:59 pc-fred NetworkManager[742]: <info> [1690621619.1930]
manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no enabled: yes)
juil. 29 11:06:59 pc-fred NetworkManager[742]: <info> [1690621619.1932]
device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 11:06:59 pc-fred ModemManager[850]: <info>
[sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
juil. 29 11:06:59 pc-fred NetworkManager[742]: <info> [1690621619.2074]
manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
juil. 29 11:06:59 pc-fred NetworkManager[742]: <info> [1690621619.2088]
device (wlp1s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 11:06:59 pc-fred NetworkManager[742]: <info> [1690621619.3978]
device (wlp1s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 11:06:59 pc-fred NetworkManager[742]: <info> [1690621619.4551]
device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 11:07:00 pc-fred systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
juil. 29 11:07:00 pc-fred systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
juil. 29 11:07:00 pc-fred systemd-sleep[9853]: Entering sleep state
'suspend'...
juil. 29 11:07:00 pc-fred kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
-- Boot 8eb1c29676604afb978454772236921d --
juil. 29 11:17:22 pc-fred kernel: BIOS may not properly restore RDRAND
after suspend, hiding RDRAND via CPUID. Use rdrand=force to reenable.
juil. 29 11:17:22 pc-fred kernel: input: Sleep Button as
/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
juil. 29 11:17:22 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
juil. 29 11:17:22 pc-fred kernel: x86/pm: family 0x15 cpu detected, MSR
saving is needed during suspending.
juil. 29 11:17:22 pc-fred kernel: ata1.00: Features: Dev-Sleep
juil. 29 11:17:29 pc-fred systemd-logind[795]: Watching system buttons
on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
-- Boot 91dc9f8c3198476d8b86571ad215f6b8 --
juil. 29 11:29:23 pc-fred kernel: BIOS may not properly restore RDRAND
after suspend, hiding RDRAND via CPUID. Use rdrand=force to reenable.
juil. 29 11:29:23 pc-fred kernel: input: Sleep Button as
/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
juil. 29 11:29:23 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
juil. 29 11:29:23 pc-fred kernel: x86/pm: family 0x15 cpu detected, MSR
saving is needed during suspending.
juil. 29 11:29:23 pc-fred kernel: ata1.00: Features: Dev-Sleep
juil. 29 11:29:30 pc-fred systemd-logind[796]: Watching system buttons
on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
-- Boot 674fc68e33c84c12bffcae069959c1a0 --
juil. 29 11:40:59 pc-fred kernel: BIOS may not properly restore RDRAND
after suspend, hiding RDRAND via CPUID. Use rdrand=force to reenable.
juil. 29 11:40:59 pc-fred kernel: input: Sleep Button as
/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
juil. 29 11:40:59 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
juil. 29 11:40:59 pc-fred kernel: x86/pm: family 0x15 cpu detected, MSR
saving is needed during suspending.
juil. 29 11:40:59 pc-fred kernel: ata1.00: Features: Dev-Sleep
juil. 29 11:41:06 pc-fred systemd-logind[840]: Watching system buttons
on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
-- Boot 9d53812554664f7ba75b88e8e305f30e --
juil. 29 11:48:17 pc-fred kernel: BIOS may not properly restore RDRAND
after suspend, hiding RDRAND via CPUID. Use rdrand=force to reenable.
juil. 29 11:48:17 pc-fred kernel: input: Sleep Button as
/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
juil. 29 11:48:17 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
juil. 29 11:48:17 pc-fred kernel: x86/pm: family 0x15 cpu detected, MSR
saving is needed during suspending.
juil. 29 11:48:17 pc-fred kernel: ata1.00: Features: Dev-Sleep
juil. 29 11:48:25 pc-fred systemd-logind[853]: Watching system buttons
on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
-- Boot db095f9eb42e47b6ae2eabe6d6f6083b --
juil. 29 11:51:04 pc-fred kernel: BIOS may not properly restore RDRAND
after suspend, hiding RDRAND via CPUID. Use rdrand=force to reenable.
juil. 29 11:51:04 pc-fred kernel: input: Sleep Button as
/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
juil. 29 11:51:04 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
juil. 29 11:51:04 pc-fred kernel: x86/pm: family 0x15 cpu detected, MSR
saving is needed during suspending.
juil. 29 11:51:04 pc-fred kernel: ata1.00: Features: Dev-Sleep
juil. 29 11:51:11 pc-fred systemd-logind[794]: Watching system buttons
on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
juil. 29 12:36:21 pc-fred NetworkManager[741]: <info> [1690626981.1701]
manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no enabled: yes)
juil. 29 12:36:21 pc-fred NetworkManager[741]: <info> [1690626981.1703]
device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 12:36:21 pc-fred NetworkManager[741]: <info> [1690626981.1806]
manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
juil. 29 12:36:21 pc-fred NetworkManager[741]: <info> [1690626981.1813]
device (wlp1s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 12:36:21 pc-fred ModemManager[839]: <info>
[sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
juil. 29 12:36:21 pc-fred NetworkManager[741]: <info> [1690626981.3511]
device (wlp1s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 12:36:21 pc-fred NetworkManager[741]: <info> [1690626981.4095]
device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 12:36:25 pc-fred fprintd[6321]: Failed to install a sleep delay
inhibitor: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The
operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
-- Boot f2d9a40e84fc4055b1a4937c1a8f16d9 --
juil. 29 12:36:54 pc-fred kernel: BIOS may not properly restore RDRAND
after suspend, hiding RDRAND via CPUID. Use rdrand=force to reenable.
juil. 29 12:36:54 pc-fred kernel: input: Sleep Button as
/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
juil. 29 12:36:54 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
juil. 29 12:36:54 pc-fred kernel: x86/pm: family 0x15 cpu detected, MSR
saving is needed during suspending.
juil. 29 12:36:54 pc-fred kernel: ata1.00: Features: Dev-Sleep
juil. 29 12:37:01 pc-fred systemd-logind[794]: Watching system buttons
on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
-- Boot aa353a3787734f2e9bd049f8b287d5b5 --
juil. 29 12:44:41 pc-fred kernel: BIOS may not properly restore RDRAND
after suspend, hiding RDRAND via CPUID. Use rdrand=force to reenable.
juil. 29 12:44:41 pc-fred kernel: input: Sleep Button as
/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
juil. 29 12:44:41 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
juil. 29 12:44:41 pc-fred kernel: x86/pm: family 0x15 cpu detected, MSR
saving is needed during suspending.
juil. 29 12:44:41 pc-fred kernel: ata1.00: Features: Dev-Sleep
juil. 29 12:44:47 pc-fred systemd-logind[773]: Watching system buttons
on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
-- Boot 9e4c8f9cbe1b443ba46507edcf1914f1 --
juil. 29 13:48:56 pc-fred kernel: BIOS may not properly restore RDRAND
after suspend, hiding RDRAND via CPUID. Use rdrand=force to reenable.
juil. 29 13:48:56 pc-fred kernel: input: Sleep Button as
/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
juil. 29 13:48:56 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
juil. 29 13:48:56 pc-fred kernel: x86/pm: family 0x15 cpu detected, MSR
saving is needed during suspending.
juil. 29 13:48:56 pc-fred kernel: ata1.00: Features: Dev-Sleep
juil. 29 13:49:02 pc-fred systemd-logind[779]: Watching system buttons
on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
juil. 29 13:54:27 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690631667.7620]
manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no enabled: yes)
juil. 29 13:54:27 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690631667.7622]
device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 13:54:27 pc-fred ModemManager[827]: <info>
[sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
juil. 29 13:54:27 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690631667.7736]
manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
juil. 29 13:54:27 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690631667.7741]
device (wlp1s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 13:54:27 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690631667.9743]
device (wlp1s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 13:54:28 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690631668.0232]
device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 13:54:29 pc-fred systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
juil. 29 13:54:29 pc-fred systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
juil. 29 13:54:29 pc-fred systemd-sleep[6151]: Entering sleep state
'suspend'...
juil. 29 13:54:29 pc-fred kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use
no_console_suspend to debug)
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system
sleep state S3
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep
state S3
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred kernel: PM: suspend exit
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred systemd-sleep[6151]: System returned from
sleep state.
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service:
Deactivated successfully.
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred systemd-logind[779]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred ModemManager[827]: <info>
[sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
juil. 29 14:18:53 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690633133.9936]
manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes enabled: yes)
juil. 29 14:29:53 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690633793.4670]
manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no enabled: yes)
juil. 29 14:29:53 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690633793.4672]
device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 14:29:53 pc-fred ModemManager[827]: <info>
[sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
juil. 29 14:29:53 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690633793.4810]
manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
juil. 29 14:29:53 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690633793.4814]
device (wlp1s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 14:29:53 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690633793.6898]
device (wlp1s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 14:29:53 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690633793.7578]
device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 14:29:54 pc-fred systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
juil. 29 14:29:54 pc-fred systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
juil. 29 14:29:54 pc-fred systemd-sleep[6684]: Entering sleep state
'suspend'...
juil. 29 14:29:54 pc-fred kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
juil. 29 15:21:13 pc-fred kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use
no_console_suspend to debug)
juil. 29 15:21:13 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system
sleep state S3
juil. 29 15:21:13 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
juil. 29 15:21:13 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep
state S3
juil. 29 15:21:13 pc-fred kernel: PM: suspend exit
juil. 29 15:21:13 pc-fred systemd-sleep[6684]: System returned from
sleep state.
juil. 29 15:21:14 pc-fred systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service:
Deactivated successfully.
juil. 29 15:21:14 pc-fred systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
juil. 29 15:21:14 pc-fred systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
juil. 29 15:21:14 pc-fred systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
juil. 29 15:21:14 pc-fred systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
juil. 29 15:21:14 pc-fred systemd-logind[779]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
juil. 29 15:21:14 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690636874.0295]
manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes enabled: yes)
juil. 29 15:21:14 pc-fred ModemManager[827]: <info>
[sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
juil. 29 16:06:00 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690639560.1354]
manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no enabled: yes)
juil. 29 16:06:00 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690639560.1357]
device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 16:06:00 pc-fred ModemManager[827]: <info>
[sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
juil. 29 16:06:00 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690639560.1469]
manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
juil. 29 16:06:00 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690639560.1472]
device (wlp1s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 16:06:00 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690639560.3602]
device (wlp1s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 16:06:00 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690639560.4017]
device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 16:06:01 pc-fred systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
juil. 29 16:06:01 pc-fred systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
juil. 29 16:06:01 pc-fred systemd-sleep[10673]: Entering sleep state
'suspend'...
juil. 29 16:06:01 pc-fred kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use
no_console_suspend to debug)
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system
sleep state S3
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep
state S3
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred kernel: PM: suspend exit
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred systemd-sleep[10673]: System returned from
sleep state.
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service:
Deactivated successfully.
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred systemd-logind[779]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690646486.9547]
manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes enabled: yes)
juil. 29 18:01:26 pc-fred ModemManager[827]: <info>
[sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
juil. 29 20:27:01 pc-fred ModemManager[827]: <info>
[sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
juil. 29 20:27:01 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690655221.7095]
manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no enabled: yes)
juil. 29 20:27:01 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690655221.7096]
device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 20:27:01 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690655221.7246]
manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
juil. 29 20:27:01 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690655221.7263]
device (wlp1s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 20:27:01 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690655221.8819]
device (wlp1s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 20:27:01 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690655221.9475]
device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
juil. 29 20:27:02 pc-fred systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
juil. 29 20:27:02 pc-fred systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
juil. 29 20:27:02 pc-fred systemd-sleep[16661]: Entering sleep state
'suspend'...
juil. 29 20:27:02 pc-fred kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use
no_console_suspend to debug)
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system
sleep state S3
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep
state S3
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred kernel: PM: suspend exit
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred systemd-sleep[16661]: System returned from
sleep state.
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service:
Deactivated successfully.
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred systemd-logind[779]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
juil. 29 21:09:32 pc-fred NetworkManager[738]: <info> [1690657772.9717]
manager: sleep: wake requested (s
```

Some pics of the BIOS : https://imgur.com/a/OzONUyu

Comment: Please [disable TPM](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1047459/) in BIOS and see if your system suspends and resumes correctly ... If not, then add the output off `journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1day'`

Comment: @Raffa Thank you for your answer. I didn't succeed to disable TPM, the BIOS is very old (see images links), there is no mention "Trusted Platform" or TPM.
So I searched, and looked at this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341629/how-to-determine-if-computer-has-tpm-trusted-platform-module-available
I posted a command result in the main post, but it seems there is no TPM chip.
Also, I didn't find anithing at /dev/tpm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your output of `journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1day'`:

> kernel: BIOS may not properly restore RDRAND after suspend, hiding RDRAND via CPUID. Use rdrand=force to reenable.

... is telling you that [RDRAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND) is [currently hidden](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/776cb5c2d33e7fd0d2893904724c0e52b394f24a.1565817448.git.thomas.lendacky@amd.com/)(*made default recently in newer kernels for compatibility with older AMD CPU chips*) which is similar to disabling it ... But, your CPU chip [AMD® A10-9620p](https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-A10-Series%20A10-9620P.html#cpuid) supports RDRAND capability and you should try re-enabling RDRAND by adding the kernel boot parameter `rdrand=force` to your `/etc/default/grub` file by changing the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash rdrand=force"
```

then, updating GRUB with:

```
sudo update-grub
```

then, rebooting your machine.

**Note**, that will re-enable RDRAND support on the kernel level and assuming your BIOS firmware can correctly receive/send related kernel signals, then your system has got a fairly high chance of getting that resume issue fixed ... Otherwise, you're most likely bound to tolerating that issue until either a newer BIOS firmware or a newer kernel offers a fix for that.

Comment: Seems to be working. Thank you!